# Use of LINQ on Arbitrary Tables

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I love LINQ esp. LINQ to SQL. The use of LINQ for static tables (where the structure of the table is known before hand) is great.

I now have a list of tables where I only know the Table Name (as a string). I also know that each row in the table would have an ID/Primary Key(int) and a number of undetermined columns whose datatypes are varchar/string. I can get the names of the columns using [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx).

I am wondering what is the best way to query these columns e.g. run a distinct on each of them? LINQ to SQL seems to be pretty efficient by converting the query directly to SQL. I would prefer not to write the SQL by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ works with types - if you don't have classes generated for your tables you can't really use LINQ. You're trying to use strongly-typed tool in a non-strongly-typed scenario.

You probably need a SQL builder library, like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13419/SelectQueryBuilder-Building-complex-and-flexible-S

Comment: Thank you Jakub Konecki. While I have not yet tried this out, this may be the way to go since it supports Distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe dynamic linq would satisfy your needs

[Dynamic LINQ (Part 1: Using the LINQ Dynamic Query Library)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Download it from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio//bb894665.aspx)

Snippet:

```
// your columnnames would be more dynamic :)
string columnName1 = "id";
string columnName2 = "someOther";

// to execute a dynamic query simple put the columnnames with your 
yourContext.SomeItems
    .Where(string.Format("{0} == 123 and {1} > 4",columnName1, columnName2);
```

Comment: I don't think O.O. can create a context in the first place, as the tables are not available at design time.

Comment: That's right. It doesn't work under these conditions (no known columnnames). My fault :)

Comment: I am sorry this will not work for me, because as mentioned I only know the DB Name at compile time. Nothing else. Thank you though.